# Can I use a physical phone for debugging in Android Studio wirelessly?

Tags: android-studio, remote-debugging, android-bluetooth, android-wireless

Debugging apps on a physical device (in my opinion) is better than using an emulator.

I was wondering if it's possible connect my phone to my computer via Bluetooth (or wirelessly) without a USB connection.

The wire kind of get in the way sometimes.

Comment: You have  **ADB Network Debugging** in android.[Check out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: @Srinivasan thanks a lot, that was very helpful.